# Jquery menu breaking on fast clicking/ scrolling over

Tags: jquery, drupal

I have this jquery code below, but the problem is that if I scroll over and out of the trigger element quickly and through the menu, then it breaks, progressively showing less elements each time until nothing is shown. Can I add a timer or easing to stop this breaking?

```
<ul class="buying-dropdown">
 <li><p class="green-button"><a href="#">Read the blog</a></p>
    <ul>
      <li class="first amazon"><a href="#">paperback</a></li>
      <li class="signed"><a href="#">Signed edition</a></li>
      <li class="kindle"><a href="#">kindle edition</a></li>
      <li class="hardback"><a href="#">hardback edition</a></li>
      <li class="last postcard"><a href="#">postcard edition</a></li>
     </ul> </li>
```

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.weaveoftheride = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

 console.log('called');
$('.buying-dropdown li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);          
        }
    );
}

};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should force jQuery to clear the animation queue and jump to the end of the animation when using the `.stop()` method, i.e. `.stop(true, true)`.